# @supports not support clip-path, at least on styled-components

Tags: css, styled-components

when i was developing a module on styled-components i found a problem with @supports (clip-path: circle())

```
const Element = styled.div`
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: circle();

  @supports (clip-path: circle()) {
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
`;
```

It seems like @supports not work with clip-path. Does anyone have any idea about this? the issue is it CSS or styled-components?

Comment: i know it is possible to use other property for this. For example @supports(display: grid)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add some value to the circle. For example:

```
.smooth-pie-2 {
    display:none;
}
@supports(clip-path: circle(50%)) {
    .smooth-pie-2 {
        display:block;
    }   
}
```